# How do I punctuate a question that contains a quote that is a declarative sentence?

Tags: punctuation

I'm stuck.  A friend of mine stated on Facebook how much she hates the music that ice cream trucks play.  So, I responded:

How about they play, "Hello.  It's ice cream you're looking for"?

It looks wrong.  I don't know if I should put a period after 'for' or not.

Please help.

Comment: Before someone weighs in with a "The correct way to punctuate here is ...", let me say that I've seen recommendations (a) always to avoid 'double punctuation' and thus write _Did you say "It's good to see you"?_, and (b) to use double punctuation where it adds clarification (_Did you say "It's good to see you!"?_ // _Did you write 'It's good to see you.'?_) Style guides are just that: guides.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct as it is (except I'd remove the comma after 'play').

> How about they play "Hello. It's ice cream you're looking for"?

And, no, you don't need a period after 'for'. [I know I violated the rule of period inside quote in the sentence you just read, but it was deliberate. This is becoming increasingly acceptable.] But I think you can, if you want.

Here's a succinct discussion with example sentences: http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/quotes.asp

Comment: But it's a style guide. There are others.

Comment: True, and I'm curious to know which style guides suggest otherwise.

Comment: I don't really want to re-cover this ground yet again, but [here](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/quotation_(speech)_marks_punctuation_in_or_out.htm) are two style guides in one. (Don't use the terms 'UK convention' and 'US convention' slavishly.)